# How to select all children except x from a HTML node

Tags: html, ruby, css-selectors, nokogiri

I have a block of HTML from which I need to extract text:

```
<div class="comment">
  <span class="c00">
  TEXT
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="reply">reply</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Note that 'TEXT' is a text node with no HTML tags within `span class="c00"`.

How do I select all texts *without* `div class="reply"`?

I tried the `:not` operator:

```
.c00:not(.reply)
```

but that did not work.

Comment: I'll point out that putting block-level elements (`p` and `div`) inside the `span` is [generally frowned-upon.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) You should consider whether you can/should change the markup, which would give you the opportunity to wrap that one rogue text node with a tag to make selecting it easier.

Comment: That's what I've gathered so far too. I'm working on this as part of a website scraping exercise, the code above is from a site we are scraping from..

Comment: @Dre: "generally frowned-upon" That's putting it really mildly.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". When asking about a problem with your code we need the minimum code that demonstrates the problem. Without the code it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the solution for you and without the expected output we don't know if the the goal has been met.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'd use:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(<<EOT)
<div class="comment">
  <span class="c00">
  TEXT
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="reply">reply</div>
  </span>
</div>
EOT

span = doc.at('span.c00')
text_nodes = [ span.children.first.text.strip ]
text_nodes +=  span.search('p').map(&:text)
text_nodes # => ["TEXT", "text", "text"]
```

Sometimes there's not a clear-cut or easy path but, by breaking down the problem into simple steps, it will usually fall into place.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you can't. Just set styles for `.c00` and overwrite it in `.reply`:

```css
.c00 {
  color: #F00;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
}
.reply {
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <span class="c00">
  TEXT
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <div class="reply">reply</div>
  </span>
</div>
```